# Powershell Match input from 2 containers with Like Wildcard

Tags: powershell, foreach, match, wildcard

new to powershell and i'm kind of stuck.

I would like to get all SCCM Tasksequnece with WMI, and match them with the image name

```
$TaskSequence = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer 

$ImagePackage = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_ImagePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer
```

> **Output of `$TaskSequence.name` is**
>   Windows Server 2012 R2 X64
>   Windows 10 Enterprise x64 USMT Full OS
>   Upgrade 1703
>   Windows 10 Enterprise x64 USMT Hardlinks
>   Windows 7 Enterprise x64 en-US
>   Windows 10 Enterprise x64 1703 en-US
>   Windows Server 2016
>
> **Output of `$ImagePackage.name` is** 
>   Windows Server 2016 x64
>   Windows 10 Enterprise x64

I tried with this foreach loop, but cant seem to get it working, this post 7 hints, there should only be 4 hints, 3 Windows 10, and 1 Windows server 2016

```
foreach ($TS in $TaskSequence ) { 

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer | 
    ForEach-Object{
        Get-WmiObject SMS_ImagePackage -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -ComputerName $SiteServer | Where-Object { $_.name -like "*$($TS.Name)*"} 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
After the question changed a little here is the new code:

```
$SiteCode = "SiteCode"
$SiteServer = "Server"
$TaskSequence = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer)
$ImagePackage = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_ImagePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer)

Foreach($Task in $TaskSequence){
    foreach($Image in $ImagePackage){ 
        if($Task.Name -like "*$($Image.Name)*" -or $Image.Name -like "*$($Task.Name)*"){ 
            $Task
            #I have no idea what you want to do with this object
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see above comment

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The answer should do what you asked for in the question

Comment: @user7490700 and please don't post a question as an answer

Comment: The comment was too long, so i could not post it..

I need to fit it like this, can you help ? 

`Foreach($Task in $TaskSequence){
    foreach($Image in $ImagePackage){
        if($Task -like "*$Image*"){

         $TaskSequencePackage = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer| where-object {$_.Name -like ("*" + $Task.Name + "*") }
         $TaskSequencePackage.Get()

        }
    }
}`

Comment: I have changed the code. But I don't understand what you want to do with the task variable

Comment: Hi that seems more like it,
but i get all tasksequences now, i should only get Windows 10 and Windows server 2016.. but i also get Windows 7, Windows server 2012 and Update 1703 ?

Comment: If i delete  .Name at the end in $ImagePackage = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_ImagePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer).Name

i get only Windows 10, so that gets me closer.. Windows server 2016 is still missing though ?

Comment: Now it should match 2016 too. And I remove the .Name at th second line, that was wrong

Comment: Great, this is really great, i'm one step closer now.. 
do you mind look at his code, and tell why it's only the Windows server 2016 tasksequence that's gets updated ? 

[link](https://pastebin.com/fmBh1iTa)

Comment: if this answer answered your question, then please mark it as solution and if you have more questions please open a new one.